# Preciso Selecionar o ultimo ID de uma ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma `ViewData` com as minhas ordens de produção. Eu estou a fazer uma `app` em que um operador pode criar uma produção nova a partir da ordem de produção selecionada, mas o ideal era ele não precisar de selecionar e aparecer automaticamente o ultimo ID da ordem de produção.

Estou a trabalhar com `ASP-NET C# razor pages`.

Este é o meu ViewData no controller:

```
 ViewData["production_order_ID"] = new SelectList(_context.Production_Order, "production_order_ID", "production_order_ID");
```

Esta é a minha page:

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:10px">
                <label asp-for="Production.production_order_ID" class="control-label">Ordem de Produção:</label>
                <select id="orderList" name="ids" asp-for="Production.production_order_ID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.production_order_ID" onchange="getSensors(); myFunction(event);"></select>
            </div>
```

Agora está a mostrar o primeiro ID da ViewData mas o que eu queria era mostrar o ultimo por default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente para resolver o meu problema eu fiz

```
 ViewData["production_order_ID"] = new SelectList(_context.Production_Order.Where(c => c.User.AspNetUser.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).OrderByDescending(c => c.production_order_ID).ToList(), "production_order_ID", "production_order_ID");
```

e funcionou para o que queria. Obrigado todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O quarto parâmetro do construtor `SelectList` é o valor que você quer que venha selecionado [docs Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_).

**Tente o seguinte:**

```
int ultimoId = 0;
        int.TryParse(_context.Production_Order
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.production_order_ID)
                        .Select(r => r.production_order_ID)
                        .First().ToString(), out ultimoId);

        ViewData["production_order_ID"] = new SelectList(_context.Production_Order, "production_order_ID", "production_order_ID", ultimoId);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta. Sim isso iria funcionar, eu porém já resolvi o meu problema mas agradeço imenso pela ajuda e qualquer maneira.